# How do I parse one part of a nested query result? (Javascript and MySQL)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, foreach, es6-promise

I am trying to get a nested structure from a MySQL query, and as a result of using JSON_OBJECT, one section of my return data is stringified. The data I am currently getting looks as follows:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "body": "Does this product run big or small?",
        "date_written": 1608535907,
        "asker_name": "jbilas",
        "helpful": 8,
        "reported": 0,
        "answers": null
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "body": "How long does it last?",
        "date_written": 1594341317,
        "asker_name": "funnygirl",
        "helpful": 6,
        "reported": 0,
        "answers": "{\"65\": {\"id\": 65, \"body\": \"It runs small\", \"date\": 1605784307, \"helpful\": 1, \"reported\": 0, \"answerer_name\": \"dschulman\"}, \"89\": {\"id\": 89, \"body\": \"Showing no wear after a few months!\", \"date\": 1599089610, \"helpful\": 8, \"reported\": 0, \"answerer_name\": \"sillyguy\"}}"
    },
    {etc},
    {etc}]
```

Before sending the result of my database query back to the client, I need to parse the answers value. My initial thought was to make the result a promise, then use a forEach loop to run through each object and parse 'answers' if it is not undefined. My code to do that is organized as follows:

```
db.query(query, [req.query['product_id'], req.query['count']], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log('err err ', error);
    }
    if (!results[0]) {
      res.json('No questions found')
    } else {
      console.log(results)
      Promise.resolve(results.forEach(result => {
        if (result['answers'] !== undefined) {
          JSON.parse(result['answers']);
        }
        return results;
      }))
      .then(results => {
        console.log(results)
      })

      res.json(results.splice(0, req.query['count']));
    }
  })
```

The console log in my 'then' block returns undefined. I also tried using results.map(), but this logged a bunch of empty arrays in the then block. Any advice on how to parse the 'answers' values when they are not null for an array of objects much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, have you tried just iterating `results` and updating the `answers` property without a Promise?:

```
db.query(query, [req.query['product_id'], req.query['count']], (error, results) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log('err err ', error);
  }
  if (!results[0]) {
    res.json('No questions found')
  } else {
    console.log(results)

    results.forEach(result => {
      result.forEach((obj) => {
        obj.answers = JSON.parse(obj.answers);
      });
    });

    res.json(results.splice(0, req.query['count']));
  }
});
```